# Threads stopping prematurely for certain values

Tags: java, multithreading

**Background**

So I'm writing an application that aims to perform Monte Carlo simulations to investigate graphs that can evolve via the Moran process (evolutionary graph theory). For un-directed graphs this works perfectly but for directed graphs the application has been exhibiting strange behaviour and I can't for the life of me figure out why. What seems to happen is that when this Boolean variable isDirected is set to true, the threads exit the for loop they run in before the loop condition is met, despite working properly when isDirected is false.

The graphs are represented by an adjacency matrix so the only difference in the code when the graph is directed is that the adjacency matrix is non-symmetric, but I can't see any reason that would have an impact.

**Code**

The main relevant code is this section from the controller:

```
 //Initialise a threadPool and an array of investigators to provide each thread with an Investigator runnable
            long startTime = System.nanoTime();
            int numThreads = 4;
            Investigator[] invArray = new Investigator[numThreads];
            ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads);

            //Assign the tasks to the threads
            for(int i=0;i<numThreads;i++){
                invArray[i] = new Investigator(vertLimit,iterations,graphNumber/numThreads,isDirected,mutantFitness,vertFloor);
                threadPool.submit(invArray[i]);
            }
            threadPool.shutdown();

            //Wait till all the threads are finished, note this could cause the application to hang for the user if the threads deadlock
            try{
                threadPool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
            }catch(InterruptedException except){
                System.out.println("Thread interrupted");
            }

            //The next two blocks average the results of the different threads into 1 array
            double[] meanArray = new double[vertLimit];
            double[] meanError = new double[vertLimit];
            double[] fixProbArray = new double[vertLimit];
            double[] fixProbError = new double[vertLimit];

            for(int x=0;x<vertLimit;x++){
                for(Investigator i:invArray){
                    meanArray[x] += i.getMeanArray()[x];
                    meanError[x] += Math.pow(i.getMeanError()[x], 2);
                    fixProbArray[x] += i.getFixProbArray()[x];
                    fixProbError[x] += Math.pow(i.getFixProbError()[x], 2);
                }
                meanArray[x] = meanArray[x]/numThreads;
                fixProbArray[x] = fixProbArray[x]/numThreads;

                meanError[x] = Math.sqrt(meanError[x]);
                fixProbError[x] = Math.sqrt(fixProbError[x]);
            }

            long endTime = System.nanoTime();

            //The remaining code is for printing and producing graphs of the results
```

As well as the Investigator class, the important parts of which are shown below:

```
public class Investigator implements Runnable{

public Investigator(int vertLimit,int iterations,int graphNumber,Boolean isDirected,int mutantFitness,int... vertFloor){
//Constructor just initialises all the class variables passed in
}

public void run(){
    GraphGenerator g = new GraphGenerator();
    Statistics stats = new Statistics();

    //The outer loop iterates through graphs with increasing number of vertices, this is the problematic loop that exits too early
    for(int x = vertFloor>2?vertFloor:2; x < vertLimit; x++){                   

        System.out.println("Current vertex amount: " + x);
        double[] currentMean = new double[graphNumber];
        double[] currentMeanErr = new double[graphNumber];
        double[] currentFixProb = new double[graphNumber];
        double[] currentFixProbErr = new double[graphNumber];

        //This loop generates the required number of graphs of the given vertex number and performs a simulation on each one
        for(int y=0;y<graphNumber;y++){ 

            Simulator s = new Simulator();
            matrix = g.randomGraph(x, isDirected, mutantFitness);

            s.moranSimulation(iterations, matrix);

            currentMean[y] = stats.freqMean(s.getFixationTimes());
            currentMeanErr[y] = stats.freqStandError(s.getFixationTimes());
            currentFixProb[y] = s.getFixationProb();
            currentFixProbErr[y] = stats.binomialStandardError(s.getFixationProb(), iterations);
        }   

        meanArray[x] = Arrays.stream(currentMean).sum()/currentMean.length;
        meanError[x] = Math.sqrt(Arrays.stream(currentMeanErr).map(i -> i*i).sum());

        fixProbArray[x] = Arrays.stream(currentFixProb).sum()/currentFixProb.length;
        fixProbError[x] = Math.sqrt(Arrays.stream(currentFixProbErr).map(i -> i*i).sum());;
    }
}

//A number of getter methods also provided here
}
```

**Problem**

I've put in some print statements to work out what's going on and for some reason when I set isDirected to true the threads are finishing before x reaches the vertLimit (which I've checked is indeed the value I specified). I've tried manually using my GraphGenerator.randomGraph() method for a directed graph and it is giving the correct output as well as testing Simulator.moranSimulation() which also works fine for directed graphs when called manually and I'm not getting a thread interruption caught by my catch block so that's not the issue either.

For the same set of parameters the threads are finishing at different stages seemingly randomly, sometimes they are all on the same value of x when they stop, sometimes some of the threads will have gotten further than the others but that changes from run to run.

I'm completely stumped here and would really appreciate some help, thanks.

Comment: Your threads might be getting aborted due to an unhandled exception.  Try grabbing the Future object returned by each call to submit(), and once you have a collection of all the futures, call the .get() method on each one.  In the even that your threads are throwing an exception, .get() will throw an ExecutionException that wraps the exception actually being thrown, which you can then investigate.

Comment: You also may want to consider using the .invokeAll() method of the ExecutorService, which will block until all the tasks have completed and then return a collection of Future objects.  This is probably more idiomatic than using .shutdown() and awaitTermination() to figure out when your tasks have completed.

Comment: @djmorton thank you so much, I hadn't seen the Future interface before! It turned out to be a divide by zero error caused by a problem in my statistics class that only came up with directed graphs. Thanks for all the suggestions guys!

Comment: Also if you want to post it as a separate answer I can accept it as the solution.

Comment: Answer added below.  Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When tasks are being run by an ExecutorService, they can sometimes appear to end prematurely if an unhandled exception is thrown.

Each time you call [.submit(Runnable)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit(java.lang.Runnable)) or [.submit(Callable)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit(java.util.concurrent.Callable)) you get a [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) object back that represents the eventual completion of the task.  The Future object has a [.get()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get()) method that will return the result of the task when it is complete.  Calling this method will block until that result is available.  Also, if the task throws an exception that is not otherwise handled by your task code, the call to .get() will throw an ExecutionException which will wrap the actual thrown exception.

If your code is exiting prematurely due to an unhandled exception, call .get() on each Future object you get when you submit the task for execution (after you have submitted all the tasks you wish to) and catch any ExecutionExceptions that happen to be thrown to figure out what the actual underlying problem is.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be terminating the threads prematurely with threadPool.shutdown();

From the Docs:
This method does not wait for previously submitted tasks to complete execution. Use awaitTermination to do that.

The code invokes .shutdown before awaitTermination...